# How to have GNU's date in OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source

I do `brew search date` unsuccessfully. 
I have `coreutils` in my system. 
I could not find GNU date anywhere.

---

How can you have GNU date in OS X?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The `gdate` binary from coreutils should be the gnu date program:

```
$ gdate --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.25
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie.
```

If you don't have that in the path, perhaps `brew rm coreutils && brew install coreutils` would be a place to start as well as inspecting your `$PATH`

Comment: ...if you have to run scripts which require GNU tools (e.g. MXE make process, which will stumble when using Apple `date`), you can temporarily modify your shell with `PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"`. In that directory, a symbolic link to `gdate` *without the "g" prefix* will be provided.